# Caching secrets in lambda@edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, latency, aws-lambda-edge, secret-manager

I have a lambda@edge function which executes some functionality at edge using secret manager service, and secrets are stored in single region only in AWS.

With Lambda's rare cold starts and latency added with secret manager connection for each call, latency being added in total is close to 1-1.5 secs.

Just like Lambda extensions, is there any way Lambda@edge can make use of caching at edge?

I am aware provisioned concurrency can mitigation cold starts to some extent, but I am looking for more options to reduce latency at both touch points, 1. Lambda start times 2. secret pulls from Secret manager